# Error: The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) float, void' (libgdx)

Tags: android, arrays, random, operator-keyword

I get the message as the title says when running this code:

```
if (houseArray.size() > 0 && houseArray.get(0).getY() == random() ) {
        addNewHouse();
        addNewRightHouse();

    };
```

I want my code to run those two functions when a house passes a random Y- coordinate. 
This is the random() function:

```
private void random() {

    MathUtils.random(0, 1200);
}
```

What could I been doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand why are you trying to perform `==` on `random()` method because your method's return type is void which means it does not return anything. and if it does not return anything then you can't compare it to something.. you need to elaborate you question for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So the problem lies with the declaration of the random() method? What kind of return type should I set?

Answer (score 0):

Change your random method to this:

```
private float random() {

    return MathUtils.random(0, 1200);
}
```

Or, better still, instead of creating a method that calls another method, you could write

```
if (houseArray.size() > 0 
        && houseArray.get(0).getY() == MathUtils.random(0, 1200)) {

    addNewHouse();
    addNewRightHouse();
}
```

Comment: It still wont add those houses.. :( the two initial houses just fall to the bottom end.

Comment: @user3091110 Feel free to ask another question with the required details that will allow us to help you solve your problem.